# Copy Entire Row (Values not formulas) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy rows between multiple worksheets and while I managed to do that it only copies the formulas and not the values. I haven't used VBA for years and I just can't think of how to do it.

My existing code is:

```
Workbooks.Open filename:=NewFN
    filename = Mid(NewFN, InStrRev(NewFN, "\") + 1)


        For i = 1 To 14
            Workbooks(filename).Sheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BD Raw Data").Rows(insertRow)

            insertRow = insertRow + 1
        Next i

        Workbooks(filename).Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: Two things (1) why use a loop when you could copy the 14 rows in one shot. (2) You don't need to use `Copy`, you can replicate values by using `rng1.Value` = `rng2.Value` where rng2 is a source range and rng1 is a destination 9ranges of equal size). To copy formula `rng1.Formula' = `rng2.Formula`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice between values and formulas is made in the paste half of the process. Have a look at the PasteSpecial method specifically the xlPasteValues argument.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195818(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [`PasteSpecial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195818%28v=office.11%29.aspx)  method using the  `XlPasteType.xlPasteValues` enumeration instead of `Copy Destination`

e.g.

```
Workbooks(filename).Sheets("sheet1").Rows(i).Copy 
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BD Raw Data").Rows(insertRow).PasteSpecial Operation:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produces the error code 1004 PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Comment: Should change Operation:= to Paste:= in second line. Worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Try it

```
 Sub CopyFormulas()
'http://officevb.com

Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Sheets("sheet2")

'copy columns C from sht1 formulas to sht2

sht1.Range("C:C").Copy
sht2.Range("C:C").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This sub copy all formulas in column C from sht1 to column C in sht2

[]´s

Comment: Unfortunately the number of columns needed to be copied varies depending on which worksheet is opened meaning a column copying solution wouldn't be the right fit for me.